# ConcurrentModificationException when trying to update map key and value

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a program (without additional libraries) which would take as input a text file and make a map of words which are present in the text with the exact number of the occurences. The problem is that I'm stuck in the moment when I try to populate the HashMap with the words and the number of occurences. Below you can find the fragment of code which I'm using:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)))) {
            String content = br.readLine();
            while(content!=null){
                sb.append(content);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                content =br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String text = sb.toString();
        String[] wordArray = text.split("\\s|\\.\\s|\\,\\s|\\r\\n");
        System.out.println(wordArray.length);

        LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> wordMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        wordMap.put(wordArray[0], 1);
        for(int i=1; i<wordArray.length;i++){
            for(String key : wordMap.keySet()){
                if(key.equals(wordArray[i])){
                    wordMap.put(key, wordMap.get(key)+1);
                } else{
                    wordMap.put(wordArray[i], 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for(String key : wordMap.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " : "+ wordMap.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```

I was trying to use Iterators the make to modifications to the HashMap but I ended up with the same exception.

One additional thing is that I also face a problem with splitting the text. In the wordArray there are present empty values. These empty values are present after the last word in the line so I suppose these are the \r\n white signs. Unfortunately adding \r\n to regex in split method did not make any difference. Could you help also with these problem?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. This is my first question on stackoverflow so sorry for any mistakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate on `wordMap.keySet()` and while iterating you are adding element to the map with `wordMap.put`.

What you want to do is:

```
for(String word : wordArray) {
    Integer count = wordMap.get(word);
    if(count == null) {           // first time for "word" => insert 1
        wordMap.put(word, 1);
    } else {                      // else increment the count
        wordMap.put(word, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jean for an answer works perfectly now. You proposed much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `worldMap.put`, which modifies the Hash Map, while an iteration (`for(String key : worldMap.keySet())` is in progress. The keyset might change while iterating over the keyset. This causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You loop code should change to this

```
for(int i=1; i<wordArray.length;i++){
    if(wordMap.containsKey(wordArray[i])){
        wordMap.put(wordArray[i], wordMap.get(wordArray[i])+1);
    } else{
        wordMap.put(wordArray[i], 1);
    }
}
```

Here we are not modifying the map but not looping thought the key set.

Comment: Thank you wrongAnswer for an answer :) works fine now.